# Script com Node.js não gerando saída

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

Olá! Comecei a resolver problemas da plataforma URIOnlineJudge e no primeiro desafio já tive dúvidas em relação à solução com node.js. O problema só pede para inserir dois números inteiros (um em cada linha) e o script deve retornar a soma deles no formato pedido. A solução foi aceita na plataforma, contudo quando rodo o script no meu terminal nenhuma saída nunca é gerada. Por que pode estar ocorrendo isso? Segue o script:

```js
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8'); 
var lines = input.split('\n');

var a = parseInt(lines.shift()); 
var b = parseInt(lines.shift()); 
var x = a + b;

console.log('X = ' + x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tudo bem, V. Rodrigues?

O que tá acontecendo, é que quando você roda isso na plataforma, você insere os números e eles ficam disponíveis dentro do diretório `/dev/stdin`, no servidor onde a plataforma está rodando.

Eu não sou especialista em questões de SO, mas até onde sei, o `/dev/stdin` é um arquivo que armazena os inputs (dados de entrada), por isso ele pede pra vc digitar e os consome de lá.

Pra simular isso na sua máquina com esse mesmo código, vc precisaria inserir 2 valores um embaixo do outro, no arquivo `/dev/stdin` de alguma forma, compreende?

O que você pode fazer também é criar um arquivo qualquer e fazer a leitura dele, o que dá no mesmo. Veja o exemplo: https://repl.it/repls/DeadlySalmonTrust

Um abraço

Comment: Olá, Diogo. Tudo bem? Passando algum arquivo como primeiro argumento da função readFileSync o script funciona, mas não consegui ainda fazer o script executar apenas inserindo dados no terminal. Gostaria de fazer o script acima funcionar haha. Usando a biblioteca 'readline-sync' consegui resolver facilmente o problema. Não é possível fazer alterações no arquivo stdin, por que ele é uma representação da entrada padrão oferecida pelo usuário, que no caso é o teclado. Mesmo assim o script não funciona. Acho isso muito estranho.